# Create a random number which doesn't change in a class constructor

Tags: c#, class, variables, random, constructor

I want to create a random number in my text box when the text is changed.
My problem is that the random number always change, when I change the text field. I just want to create the variable once. How to do this?

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication5
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()                  // constructor of Form1
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Rand m = new Rand();
            textBox1.Text = m.myRand.ToString();
        }
    }

    public class Rand
    {
        public int myRand = new Random().Next(10);
        public Rand() { }
    }
}
```

Comment: just use a bool to remember that you already generated a number..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just make your class static and use static `myRand` variable.

```
public static class Rand
{
    public static int myRand;
    static Rand() {
        myRand = new Random().Next(10);
    }
}
```

Now you don't even need to create a new class. Just do `textBox1.Text = Rand.myRand;`
`myRand` will be initialized just once in the lifetime of the object.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood the question correctly, you can just refactor m to be a field of Form1:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication5
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Rand m = new Rand();            // m is generated only once
        public Form1()                  // constructor of Form1
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = m.myRand.ToString();
        }
    }

    public class Rand
    {
        public int myRand = new Random().Next(10);
        public Rand() { }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Oleg, but I choose the answer of Empereur. The use of static makes sense here.

Answer (score 1):

create two variables in Form1:

```
Rand number;
bool firstime = true;
```

and on textBox1_TextChanged():

```
if(firstime)
{
   number = new Rand();
   textBox1.Text = number.myRand.ToString();
   firstime = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the code right after The statement : InitializeComponent(); which is the constructor for the form.  Declare the variable in global space, not inside a function.

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication5
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Rand m = new Rand();
        public Form1()                  // constructor of Form1
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            textBox1.Text = m.myRand.ToString();
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }

    public class Rand
    {
        public int myRand = new Random().Next(10);
        public Rand() { }
    }
}​
```